# Radiation EIRP impact on organisms

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, power, antennas, molecular-dynamics

I read some documentation about how harmless the non ionizing radiation can be and it looks like the arguments are around the frequency(hence the energy) of the wave. In the sense that a particle with a low energy cannot affect the molecular structure of an organism.

However there is also the EIRP of a radiation source which is linked to the emitter power.

It is true that radiations with frequencies above 2.1GHz(GSM frequency), for example light, can be found in nature and can be assumed that do not affect people, but what about the EIRP. For example, an antenna with EIRP = 1100 W. Is this value low or high compared to what is in nature?

Although we consider that the frequency is too low to affect molecules, on such EIRP, couldn't be the case where anomalies can occur and the people to be affected by the radiation after long exposure at a distance, let's say about 50 meters (~160 feet)?

I'm not a physicist, I just try to document myself on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

The [solar constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant) is about $1360\,\mathrm{W/m2}$.  This is the amount of energy which reaches the top of the atmosphere (and it varies a little depending on where the Earth is in its orbit &c &c).  The amount of energy actually reaching the surface is lower, and can vary between about $500\,\mathrm{W/m2}$ and $1000\,\mathrm{W/m2}$ (obviously on a clear day, with the Sun directly overhead: it is much lower at night!).

Let's now consider an omnidirectional transmitter (transmitters often are not omnidirectional, and this is going to give a low estimate as a result), which is radiating $P$.  If you are a distance $r$ from this transmitter then the amount of power per unit area is

$$\frac{P}{4\pi r^2}$$

So, we can consider your transmitter, of $P=1100\,\mathrm{W}$ at a distance of $r=50\,\mathrm{m}$.  The power per unit area at this distance is $3.5\times 10^{-2}\,\mathrm{W/m^2}$.

Taking the lower end of the Sun's surface flux, this is lower by a factor of more than four orders of magnitude.

I'm not sure what the effective surface area of a human is, but let's say $2\,\mathrm{m^2}$.  At this distance, the amount of power you might absorb from this object is about $7\times 10^{-2}\,\mathrm{W} = 70\,\mathrm{mW}$, while from the Sun you might absorb $1\,\mathrm{kW}$ (you don't, because you reflect a lot the light).

If you can survive outside, and if the radiation from this thing is not specially harmful (ionizing, for instance) then you are not going to be worried about it.  It might be a problem for very sensitive vampires, but probably not even then.